# How to copy jar-with-dependencies in my webapp\myfolder in maven Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-web-start, jnlp

I have the maven project in Idea with two modules: 1)web and 2)web-start-swt-jar.

The web-start-swt-jar pom.xml is configured to package with-dependencies.

My project looks like this:

```
[root]
  - web-start-swt-jar   pom.xml (packaging jar)
  - web  pom.xml (packaging war)
 pom.xml (packaging pom)
```

Is it possible to make theese steps I wanted to:

1. Compile,pacakge with dependensies the web-start-swt-jar.
2. Compile, package the web module with copying the recently packaged web-start-swt-jar to webapp\webstartFolder\ ?

Yes I use maven assemply plugin, but it copy the jar file wich without dependencies.

Thank you!

p.s. May be you suggest to use some plugins to comfort work with web-start? e.g. webstart-maven-plugin ? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be answer was found: using `maven-shade-plugin` to package jar with dependensies and `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy to custom folder in `prepare-package` phase.

Dont forget to set version of depended jar via `<dependency managament>`

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>



<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webstart-swt-jar</artifactId>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/SomeFolderHere
                                    </outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>(optional rename..)webstart-swt-jar.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>

                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**ADDED:**
But if I dont set `webstart-swt-jar` to dependency, build failed with error "webstart-swt-jar not found". Its not good, because artifact is duplicated in WEB-INF\lib and my \custom folder...

Answer (score 1):

```
[root]
  - web-start-swt-jar   pom.xml (packaging jar)
  - web  pom.xml (packaging war)
 pom.xml (packaging pom)
```

Try to add this : web pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-start-swt-jar</artifactId>
</dependency>

 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                 <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>web-start-swt-jar</artifactId>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <!-- outputDirectory not sure. to test-->
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/webstartFolder</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>web-start-swt-jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems> 
              <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```